# How to make this gaema demo running on google-app-engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gaema

[This](http://code.google.com/p/gaema/source/checkout) is the package which has a webapp demo in it.

However, when I login use this demo, I get an error.

How to make this demo running on the gae-launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in gaema.

The line that's failing is trying to urlencode a dictionary of arguments that get passed to the OpenID endpoint. One or more of the values, perhaps your first or last name, has non-ASCII characters.

You might be able to work around it by replacing instances of this:

```
urllib.urlencode(args)
```

With this:

```
urllib.urlencode(dict([(k, args[k].encode('utf-8')) for k in args]))
```

For a more permanent fix, I would report the issue here:

http://code.google.com/p/gaema/issues/list